# CloudKit Issue: did not find required record type

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

### My Situation:

- In my CloudKit Dashboard, I set a record in the `PRIVATE DATA`'s `Default Zone` for testing the function of Downloading data from iCloud.
- The thing is, there is no error occurred in my iPhone Simulator or the App translated to my phone through Xcode.
- But when I posted my App to the `TestFlight`, the App downloaded from `TestFlight` occurred the error, `did not find required recored type`.

[image]

The thing worth be mentioned that the `CardModel` is a `Recode Types` in the CloudKit Dashboard.

### My Code:

```
   let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
   let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
   let query = CKQuery(recordType: "CardModel", predicate: predicate)
   self.privateDB.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) {
        results, error in
        if error != nil {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.delegate?.errorUpdating(error)
                println("error loading: \(error)")
            }
```

After checking my code, I find the error is submitted by `self.privateDB.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil)`. And the `errorUpdating()` is the function in it's Class's Protocol Part.

### My Question:

- Why I got different results between the App translated by Xcode and the App downloaded from `TestFlight`?
- I know I get to show more code, but I have no idea which part of system occurred the error. CloudKit or the certification of iCloud?

A big appreciation for your guide and answer.

Ethan Joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you deploy your data from Development to Production region in CloudKit Dashboard? I suppose TestFlight needs the production database, not development.

Comment: OK....I really do not know that. How stupid am I. I correct it when back to dorm. Thank you.

Comment: Deployed from development to production,still the same error. Any tips?

Comment: If you work with private database, are you using the same user in Xcode and TestFlight?

Comment: Ah, my fault, I misunderstand the meaning of "deploy", instead of really click the deploy button,I just switched the development/production view. -_-!